# nested json with jQuery: create List of nested item

Tags: jquery, json, list, mobile

I have this JSON:

```
{
    "fakultaeten": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Carl-Friedrich Gauß",
            "institut": [
                {
                    "Mathematik": [
                        {
                            "Verbrauch": "852 kWH",
                            "Effizienz": "5,5"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Informatik": [
                        {
                            "Verbrauch": "852 kWH",
                            "Effizienz": "5,5"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Wirtschaftswissenschaften": [
                        {
                            "Verbrauch": "852 kWH",
                            "Effizienz": "5,5"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Sozialwissenschaften": [
                        {
                            "Verbrauch": "852 kWH",
                            "Effizienz": "5,5"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "verbrauch": "852 kWH"
        }
    ]
}
```

And I want to create list of all items in "institut", like this:

- Mathematik
- Infomratik
- Wirtschaftswissenschaften
- etc

I'm trying this:

```
$.each(data.fakultaeten, function(key,value)
            {
                var mother = "<li id='first'>"+value.name+"<ul>";
                $.each(value.institut, function(key1, value1)
                {
                // create the list here
                });
             })
```

The result is only: [object Object]

What is wrong with my solution?

Comment: Do you really have JSON? Or do you just have a javascript object?

Comment: I don't think it is, if you are getting `data` from an async call it is likely a javascript object. JSON can only ever be a string, if you have a string then you should parse it with `JSON.parse(jsonString)`

Comment: I do that, but didn't put it here, because it's not part of my question.

Comment: you said "I have this JSON"... if you already have it as an object, and don't want to show the parsing, then no need to mention JSON. You just confuse the situation. Besides, what part of you code doesn't work?

Comment: Anyways, I just added the information JSON, because I thought it MIGHT be important. If it's not - ignore it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `institut` is an array containing a single object, so you can reference that single object using `institut[0]`.

This will work:

```
$.each(data.fakultaeten, function (key, value) {
    var mother = "<li id='first'>" + value.name + "<ul>";
    $.each(value.institut[0], function (key1, value1) {
        alert(key1);
    });
});
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Z2JRd/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.each(data.fakultaeten, function (key, value) {
    var mother = "<li id='first'>" + value.name + "<ul>";
    $.each(value.institut[0], function (key1, value1) {
        console.log(key1); // key1 gives you output that you want
    });
});
```